# Array list - Getting next index value

Tags: java

```
public class snhu5 {

public static void main (String args[])
{
    int[] miles = {2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,25,26};
    int sum, sumA;

    sumA= 0;
    sum = 0;

    for (int count=0; count<miles.length;count++)
    {
        miles[count] = miles.nextInt();
        sum = sum + miles[count];
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of the miles ran = " + sum);

    sumA = sum/10;

    System.out.println("The average miles ran = " +sumA);

}

}
```

I am trying to create an array that uses my provided values and number of indexes to end up giving both the sum of the numbers, as well as the average of the numbers. The problem I am having is at the for loop where I wrote ;

```
{
     miles[count] = miles.nextInt();
     sum = sum + miles[count];
}
```

Any help appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int count=0; count<miles.length;count++)
 {
    sum = sum + miles[count];
 }
```

The above code is enough to calculate sum. Calculating average you can use array size here

```
float average = (float)sum / miles.length;
```

Comment: +1 for tacking into account also the average return type and for beating me to it :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the sum of the numbers in your array, just do

```
for (int count = 0; count < miles.length; count++) {
    sum += miles[count];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the "new for loop"

```
for (int milesItem : miles) {
  sum += milesItem;
}
```

Comment: That is `enhanced for loop` :)

Comment: Enhanced, new, gilded, blessed... :D

Comment: Thanks. It's a good little discussion that highlights how the functional programming paradigm is finally becomming a first-class citizen. When I did CS 20 year ago the question was "how do we get everybody to use this?" The answer is - as always - to wait for another generation to embrace it, and the old ways to die out :D

Answer (score 1):

For the sum just go the following way:

```
for (int i : miles) {
    sum += i;
}
```

Then the average:

```
sumA = sum/miles.length
```

by using length you are sure that it will work, even if the number of elements in miles increases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the below line in the `for` loop.

```
// miles[count] = miles.nextInt(); // commented, as this is not a scanner to get input from user.
```

Your `for` loop should be like this.

```
for (int count=0; count<miles.length;count++) {
    sum = sum + miles[count]; // miles[count] gets the int value from the miles array based on the count index
    // sum += miles[count]; // Even this can be used instead.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int count=0;count < miles.length ;count ++) {
    sum += miles[count];
}
```

You have to use only above code remove the `miles.nextInt()` from the loop code